# How can I debug deploy.sh when using Kudu to deploy a node.js app to Azure?

Tags: node.js, bash, azure, deployment, kudu

I am trying to deploy a node.js application (just a simple ghost blog) to Azure Websites using Kudu. I have the following lines in my deployment script (`deploy.sh`, which is referenced correctly from `.deployment`):

```
eval $NPM_CMD install grunt-cli  
exitWithMessageOnError "Problem Installing Grunt"  
./node_modules/.bin/grunt --no-color init
exitWithMessageOnError "Problem With Grunt"
```

When the deployment fails, I look into the Azure Management Portal and see the log of the failure. I get the expected output when `npm install grunt-cli` is run - i.e. a warning that it should be installed globally and a list of subpackages indicating that it has installed correctly anyway. Then, directly afterwards I get:

```
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Problem With Grunt
```

The same sequence (with no further information) is in the `log.xml` for the deployment available from the Kudu deployment dump.

How should I tackle this? Are there any other places I can look for output and errors? Can I change my script to output more error information? Where will it go if I do? Is there some way of testing my deployment script using the Kudu remote console utility?

Comment: Adding `--verbose` and `--stack` to the grunt command yields no extra information.

Comment: I've found you can test commands on the Kudu remote debug console by navigating to the directory `D:\home\site\repository`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I can't get any output even on the remote debug console. How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like it's possible to save the output of the command into a file by `./node_modules/.bin/grunt --no-color init > output.txt`. In my case the problem was solved simply by installing grunt globally.